My ASP.NET MVC app keeps on endlessly spinning after implementing CosmosClient from namespace Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos
My ASP.NET MVC app keeps on endlessly spinning after implementing CosmosClient from namespace Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.
Logic to Initialize CosmosClient :
static CosmosClient client;

public void Initialize()
{
    if (client == null)
    {
        if (tokenEnv == "Local")
        {
            credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = false,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureDeveloperCliCredential = true,
                ExcludeWorkloadIdentityCredential = true,
                ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
                ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true,
                ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["kvMsiClientId"], TenantId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantID"] });
        }

        try
        {
            client = new CosmosClient(endPointURL, credential);
        }
        catch (CosmosException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

Logic to read document:
 public async Task<dynamic> CosmosGetDocument(string id, string collection)
 {
     try
     {
         var container = client.GetContainer(DatabaseId, collection);
         ItemResponse<dynamic> response = await container.ReadItemAsync<dynamic>(id, PartitionKey.None);
         return response.Resource;
     }
     catch (CosmosException e)
     {
         if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
         {
             return null;
         }
         else
         {
             throw;
         }
     }
 }

Output in Visual Studio:
DocDBTrace Information: 0 : GlobalEndpointManager: StartLocationBackgroundRefreshWithTimer() - Invoking refresh
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.instrumentationkey.RemoteDependency","time":"2024-08-27T07:40:15.8193783Z","iKey":"InstrumentationKey","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf: 2.1.0.363","ai.device.roleInstance":"<DevDevice>"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"https://QaApp.documents.azure.com:443/","id":"u4HgAyshVG8=","value":1115.6537,"resultCode":"200","dependencyKind":1,"success":true,"properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
DocDBTrace Information: 0 : Current WriteEndpoints = (https://QaApp-southcentralus.documents.azure.com/) ReadEndpoints = (https://QaApp-southcentralus.documents.azure.com/)
DocDBTrace Information: 0 : GlobalEndpointManager: StartLocationBackgroundRefreshWithTimer() refreshing locations
The thread 31120 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 33028 has exited with code 0 (0x0).


What does "endlessly spinning" even mean? Do you mean "stuck in an infinite loop"? If so, what makes you think it's doing that, as opposed to being blocked by a synchronization primitive, or if the thread was abnormally terminated, or anything else?

Your class has a static CosmosClient field, but your void Initialize() method is an instance-method and not thread-safe. You should fix that.

Who calls CosmosGetDocument and how? The output is not showing any operation is actually being executed on the Cosmos DB SDK, those DocDBTrace lines are the client initializing but they are not related to any ReadItemAsync operation
